# What happens to skills in the training queue when an account reverts to alpha clone status?

Tags: eve-online

I have a bunch of skills queued to train, which includes advanced skills that an Alpha clone cannot train and several skills that are scheduled to start several days out. Since these two conditions are normally something an Alpha clone cannot train for, what happens to my skill queue if my account reverts to Alpha clone status with my skill queue in place?

Comment: I'd assume the moment your account switches to Alpha status any uneligible skill currently training stops training and is removed from the queue along with any other uneligible skills. Also at the same time I'd assume any skill not starting training in the next 24 hours would be removed from queue. I don't know which would happen first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As someone who has experienced this first hand the first thing that happens is that your skill queue is paused. This forces you to attend to what skills are no longer available to train. You must then remove the offending skills from the queue.